# How to capture admin permission in .qs

Tags: qt, windows-installer, qscript

I ask the system to call the maintenancetool and it asks for admin permission, how to know if the user allowed it or not in a .qs?

Comment: SO is not the place for that kind of question. Try SuperUser from StackExchange.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.